# How to return a Range of Int in Swift?

Tags: swift

How can I return a Range of Int from a function in Swift? I've searched the Swift 2.1 docs, the web, SO, and tried:

```
func myfunc() -> Range { // }
func myfunc() -> ( Int ... Int ) { // }
func myfunc() -> Range< Int >  { // }
```

... and many others ...

Sorry for being bone-headed here, and thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem with the third one?

Comment: Hi @DánielNagy, none whatsoever, apparently. I think the problem was with the comment parser in Playground--it was giving me a strange error, and it occurred at the same time as when I tried the third one. Foiled by coincidence! I'm leaving this up for someone with a similar question, as it took me a while to get to the third one... apparently mangling my comments in Xcode's Playground along the way :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your third one is correct. This compiles and works, for example:

```
func oneTo10() -> Range<Int> { 
   return 1...10 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So strange... I was getting an error in Playground, but it definitely works. I'm leaving this up in the hopes that someone at some point might have the same question and get to the answer more quickly :)

Comment: `1...10` is not Range, it is ClosedRange. `1..<11` is Range. If you want to use `1...10` you need to return `-> ClosedRange<Int> {}`

Comment: At the time this was written, it was correct. It's been a while though.

Answer (score 2):

With Swift 3, [`Range`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/range) has a smaller scope than before and comes with its counterpart [`ClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/closedrange). You now also have [`CountableClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countableclosedrange) and [`CountableRange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countablerange) in the Standard Library for objects that conform to `Strideable` protocol (including `Int`).

Thus, according to your needs, you may refactor your code by following the pattern of one of the examples below:

---

### #1. Using `CountableClosedRange`

```
func myfunc() -> CountableClosedRange<Int> {
    return 1 ... 10
}
print(Array(myfunc())) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

### #2. Using `CountableRange`

```
func myfunc() -> CountableRange<Int> {
    return 1 ..< 11
}
print(Array(myfunc())) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

### #3. Using `ClosedRange`

```
func myfunc() -> ClosedRange <Int> {
    return 1 ... 10
}
```

### #4. Using `Range`

```
func myfunc() -> Range<Int> {
    return 1 ..< 11
}
```

---

Note that, with Swift 3, `Range` and `ClosedRange` do not conform to `Sequence` protocol. As a consequence, the following code won't compile:

```
func myfunc() -> Range<Int> {
    return 1 ..< 11
}
print(Array(myfunc())) // error: Argument type 'Range<Int>' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'
```

Therefore, unless you have a good reason to use `Range` and `ClosedRange` with types that conform to `Strideable` (including `Int`), you should rely on `CountableRange` and `CountableClosedRange` for them.